# Grails withCriteria And/Or cases?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

I have the following Grails withCriteria structure:

```
allInfo = Scholarship.withCriteria {
    between('gpa', '0', gpa)
    grades {
      idEq year
    }
    scholarshipCounties {
        eq('county.id', county)
    }
    majors {
      idEq major
    }
    activities {
        idEq activity
    }
    eq('specialTypeInd', special)
}
```

I want this to return scholarships by (gpa AND grades AND majors) OR scholarshipCounties OR activities OR specialTypeInd.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using respective `or{}` and `and{}` clauses:

```
allInfo = Scholarship.withCriteria {
  and{
    between('gpa', '0', gpa)
    grades {
      idEq year
    }
    majors {
      idEq major
    }
  }
  or{
    scholarshipCounties {
        eq('county.id', county)
    }

    activities {
        idEq activity
    }
    eq('specialTypeInd', special)
  }
}
```